# Android GridLayout with fixed width columns but adjusting to device width

Tags: android, android-gridlayout, column-width

In the example below I am trying to enforce a fixed column width for a GridLayout whereby the width of the columns is driven by the device width. It works but I am not sure if there is a better way or I am missing out on any side-effects.

GridLayout:

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/twopane"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:columnCount="8"  >

    <TextView android:id="@+id/grid_id_col1" android:text="col1"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/grid_id_col2" android:text="col2" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/grid_id_col3" android:text="col3" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/grid_id_col4" android:text="col4" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/grid_id_col5" android:text="col5" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/grid_id_col6" android:text="col6" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/grid_id_col7" android:text="col7" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/grid_id_col8" android:text="col8" />

<!-- for ease of discussion I left out the actual UI layout -->
</GridLayout>
```

In the activity the width is calculated:

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

float dpWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels / displayMetrics.density;
Integer colWidth = (int) (dpWidth / 8);
```

Then the column size is set up:

```
TextView colTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.grid_id_col1);
colTv.setWidth( colWidth );
colTv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

And so on for the other columns. Using this approach I have some control of the grid structure and it is also flexible for different devices & orientations.

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: The only thing I can think of besides this is nesting your rows in a linear layout and setting their width with weights. It has the benefit of being handled by Android, but has the downside of making a little nastier xml.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am migrating from a LinearLayout (and some RelativeLayouts) to the GridLayout because the LinearLayout is nested twice and has too many levels in the hierarchy.